# Term for a powerful personal computer?

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, terminology

What term would an enthusiast use to describe a powerful, tripped-out personal computer, the kind he might custom-build in his garage and overclock to the max?

The usual reference sources are failing me here, as I'm looking for a slang/jargon term.

The closest I've found is *rig* (as in "gaming rig").

Comment: A rig is just a device that is designed with a purpose in mind. Because gaming is very resource intensive on the computer, a "gaming rig" is often automatically considered to be a mid- to high-end computer. That being said, rig is probably not an appropriate word.

Comment: In general PC usage, a "workstation-class" system is usually the highest-end, top-performing, best-equipped type of system in a product line....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think *rig* is fine here, but I've also heard *box* or *build*.

You could combine the common geek term *uber*, for *uber rig* or *uber box*.

The owner of this rig would tell you that it *screams*.

Comment: gaming rig is also common, especially if thats what it was built for

Answer (score 3):

[Ars Technica](http://arstechnica.com/) produce regular system guides ([here's the latest](http://arstechnica.com/gadgets/guides/2011/12/ars-technica-system-guide-december-2011.ars)) in which they recommend the best gaming rigs you can build at different price points.  They call their systems:

- cheapest: *Budget Box*
- mid-range: *Hot Rod*
- no expense spared: *God Box*

Comment: The God Particle is still not proven exist, though.

Comment: yeah, I was thinking about Ars as well. you could check out their forums, too for what users call their own boxen. Anyway, most terms I can think of are two words, or hyphenated.

Answer (score 1):

I've heard the word *work-horse* used in this context...